# PhpBB 3.2.2 Twig Loader Error When Using PhpBB For Website Login

Tags: php, twig, phpbb

I am trying it use the authentication of PhpBB 3.2.2 to authenticate the websites users.  I have added the code below to the top of a test page

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);

$phpbb_root_path = '/forum/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
```

The problem that I am coming across is I get a PhpBB Warning:

> [phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file `[ROOT]/phpbb/template/twig/loader.php` on line 176: Declaration of `phpbb/template/twig/loader::findTemplate($name)` should be compatible with `Twig_Loader_Filesystem::findTemplate($name, $throw = true)`

I am not trying to load a twig template I just want to access the PhpBB session data to check if a user is logged in or not.

When i navigate to the actual forum itself that works fine without any errors or warnings.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what the issue might be?

Comment: The warning says it all, the signature of the method `findTemplate` inside the class `phpbb/template/twig/loader` should have 2 parameters, `$name` and `$throw = true`

Comment: Hi DarkBee, thanks for your comment.  I understand that the method is expecting 2 parameters.  The issue is that i am not attempting to load a twig template, was just wondering why this warning is been thrown when i am not attempting to load a template.

Comment: Oh I see, well if u really wanted to find out, I guess u would need to dig through the source of phpbb in order to locate why a template is being loaded to authenticate the user

Comment: Yes, that was my next stage.  But to be honest now i have realised it is and issue with PhpBB somehow conflicting with my twig loader, i might just scrap the idea of using PhpBB as the authentication method for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a further look into this and the problem appears to be something to do with my own bootloader which sets up the twig loader for the main part of the website, this is having an issue with the twig loader for PhpBB.  As this is a different issue from the one i orginally posted i will close this question.